# Return Address from Google term search to excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search, element

I am familiar with StackOverflow but have just recently signed up. I am trying to search a Hotel on google and return the address in Excel using VBA. Below is a photo of what Information I am trying to return from Google. From my research, I was able to find a VBA that allowed me to return the Results stats.

***Would it be possible to modify my code and return the box at the top of my google search?***

I would really appreciate your help! Below is the VBA I am using to return search results.

[Sample Image - Red Roof Inn & Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjXs7.jpg)

```
Sub SearchGoogle()
 Dim ie As Object
 Dim form As Variant
 Dim button As Variant
 Dim LR As Integer
 Dim var As String
 Dim var1 As Object
 LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 For x = 2 To LR
 var = Cells(x, 1).Value
 Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
 ie.Visible = True
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://www.google.co.in"
    While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Wend
End With
 'Wait some to time for loading the page
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
 Wend
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
 ie.document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = var
 'Here we are clicking on search Button
 Set form = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set button = form(0).onsubmit
form(0).submit
 'wait for page to load
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set var1 = ie.document.getElementById("resultStats")
Cells(x, 2).Value = var1.innerText
 ie.Quit
 Set ie = Nothing
 Next x

 End Sub
```

Comment: You understand that google has a limit on the number of searches within xx minutes? If you exceed this, your ip is blocked for a short period.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will not be doing a large number of searches in a short period of time. I am just looking to automate this process.

Comment: So, you don't know how to accept an answer @Alexander Curry. I've taken out mine, thanks.

Comment: @SIM My apologies, I am new to stackflow, you supplied a sufficient answer that helped me with what i was looking for! Excuse me for being a true noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code loads the page and then loads the value of the `resultStats` element.

So the section of your code that you will need to alter is:

```
Set var1 = ie.document.getElementById("resultStats")
Cells(x, 2).Value = var1.innerText
```

The first step to your problem is to understand the DOM of the HTML page you are attempting to use, in this case Google. I would suggest using a browser to navigate the DOM as it would give you a good idea of what the whole page is doing.

If you are aiming to do this on a macro basis you will need a path through the DOM that will always take you where you want to go. I would suggest having two pages with different searches open so that you can check you hypothesis as you go.

For example the boxes that you refer to seem to be located in a class called `kp-header` from knowing this you can build out your path through the DOM to return the text value displayed on screen. Again you will need to do your own investigations to find the best stating point for your search as `kp-header` was just the first potently helpful result I could find.

Although please note that depending on the speed you are loading these webpages you may hit a limit from google as they discourage scraping. What would be a better option to avoid these limits and to avoid yourself having to investigate all of google's DOM would be to try and incorporate one of google's API's

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do not intend on scraping copious amount of data. I am just looking to automate this routine process. I will look into Google API. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @AlexanderCurry If you are not looking for more answers please consider marking one of the answers as correct so that the other users of the site know this is a closed question. If you need more information please can you elaborate what you are needing?